# Rotate issue on MVVMCross Android app. Command bindings lost when using dialog theme

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've been using MVVMCross for a couple of months now and have been very impressed so far.  However, I have come across an issue which I have as of yet been unable to resolve.

I have broken this down into the most simple solution that I can so that the problem can be reproduced.  The issue centres around having a button on an activity which is styled in a "dialog" theme.  When the device is rotated the button command bindings are lost and the buttons no longer fire the commands in the view model.  The odd thing is that all the other bindings are still working.

To simulate this I have created a solution that has

1) A simple MvxActivity that has one button.  This button opens a second activity which is styled as a dialog.

2) On this second MvxActivity I have a couple of buttons and an EditText and TextView control.  The buttons are bound to commands on the view model and the EditText and TextView are also bound to properties.

I have tried adding the following attribute to the second activity (as suggested elsewhere) but it does not work.

```
ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize
```

Here is the second view that is causing the issue.  Removing the theme attribute will make it work - but I want a dialog theme!:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views;

namespace RotateIssue.Views
{
    [Activity(Label = "MyActivity", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog")]
    public class SecondView : MvxActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SecondView);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the viewmodel for that view:

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace RotateIssue.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class SecondViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        private string _hello = "";
            public string Hello
    { 
        get { return _hello; }
        set { _hello = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Hello); }
    }

        public bool DataValid
        {
            get
            {
                return (_hello.Length > 0);
            }
        }

        private MvxCommand _saveCommand;
        public ICommand SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _saveCommand = _saveCommand ?? new MvxCommand(SaveAsset);
                return _saveCommand;
            }
        }

        private MvxCommand _cancelCommand;
        public ICommand CancelCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _cancelCommand = _cancelCommand ?? new MvxCommand(Cancel);
                return _cancelCommand;
            }
        }

        public void Cancel()
        {
             Close(this);
        }

        public void SaveAsset()
        {
            if (DataValid)
            {
                //TODO: Do something useful
                Close(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can provide the AXML if needed.  The app is targetted at API Level 16.

Comment: Maybe try adding `ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize` to the parent activity rather than to the Dialog?

Comment: Ok - that seems to do the trick!  I will have to check my main project to see if this change causes any other issues but I can't see it being a problem.  Many thanks for the swift response.